# run ssh / scp from bash script w/out password - key installed

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, scp

I try to copy files between two rpi's in the same network. Public key installed as prompted in many tutorials. When directly calling ssh or scp command from the terminal no password is asked. Running the same command from a bash script it askes for a password.

I am puzzled because most people seem to have the problem with running ssh/scp using a key at all - but this works fine. It looks like a terminal/bash difference.

The Script looks like:

script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo scp /home/pi/file.txt pi@192.168.178.xx:/home/pi/foo/
```

It is executed by

```
$sudo ./script
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: How exactly do you run it from a bash script? and how do you run the script? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Have you copied the public key of the root account to the remote machine? `sudo ssh-copy-id ...`? I'm asking because you're executing your script via `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with all tutorials is that they may follow different methods. What I normally do is the following.

Because you are using sudo (as per edit of the question) to execute your script, your script will run as root. Not as your own user.

That means that you need to add the public key of root (which is in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) from `strawberry` in the `authorized_keys` of root on `blueberry ass well!

Suppose we have two Pi's, let's call them `strawberry` and `blueberry`. `Strawberry` is the ssh-client, `blueberry` is the server.  should be replaced with your logon.

On `strawberry`:

```
cd
mkdir .ssh
chown <my name> .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
ssh-keygen
cp .ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/nice_filename
sudo -s
cd ~root
mkdir .ssh
chown root .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
ssh-keygen
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /tmp/nice_filename
chmod a+r /tmp/nice_filename
exit

scp /tmp/nice_filename blueberry: # and enter the password for blueberry
```

`ssh-keygen` may ask for a password. If you really completely trust your environment, you might choose to leave the password empty. If you do not leave the password empty, you will need to provide that password to unlock the key.

So, normally I just enter-through, leaving the password empty.

On `blueberry`:

```
cd
mkdir .ssh
chown <my name>  .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
cat nice_filename >> .ssh/authorized_keys
chown <my name>  .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
sudo -s
mkdir ~root/.ssh
chown root.root ~root/.ssh
chmod 700 ~root/.ssh
cat nice_filename >> ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown root ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Instead of the `cat id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorized_keys`, you may `mv id_rsa.pub .ssh/authorized_keys`, but you should only do this if it is really your first key or if you want to remove existing keys.

Next on `strawberry`:

```
ssh blueberry ls /tmp
ssh root@blueberry ls /usr
sudo ssh blueberry ls /var
```

et voila!

Comment: thanks for your response. this looks identical to one of the tutorials I did (tried multiple). After all of them the direct ssh or scp via comand line worked without any flaws.  -  the problem is as soon as I try to execute those same lines (scp) via a bash script a password is asked...

Comment: How do you launch your script? Under a different user? Did you put a password for unlocking the keys?

Comment: @LjmDullaart it is all te same. I didn't use any passwords other than the default pi/pi combo for the root...all was left blank

Comment: So you have a folder `/root/.ssh drwx------   root root`, on blueberry, in which you have the public key from `id_rsa.pub` root on strawberry in `authorized_keys -rw-------  root root`. On strawberry, you are root when you launch the script. (just to verify).  Can you do `grep  PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config` ? (should be yes, if you can ssh fron the cli) Does `ssh -v blueberry` provide any hints?

Comment: So, from the edit of your question, I can see that it is not the same. I've edited the answer to match your expectations, but please also look at my other answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!! - it took me 3 runs of you how to to get it to work - i realy dont know why...:D

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You mess up things while using `sudo`. Why you use `sudo` is not clear. Basically, you just seem to want to do:

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
scp /home/pi/file.txt pi@192.168.178.xx:/home/pi/foo/
```

and launch the script as

```
./script
```